# How report metal amounts as amount of their respective metal oxides?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, concentration, mole

I have performed an element analysis, and I I have calculated the amount of each metal in my sample, given in milligrams. Let's say I weighed in 10 mg of the powder. I want to see how much of that I have accounted for by the major components in my sample (those > 1-2 %).

Since my metals were not free metals in my sample, but rather as various oxides, I need to convert back to the most common oxides. This is the idea:

> If I have 1 mg $\ce{Mn}$ in my sample, how many milligrams would that be if I
>   have $\ce{MnO2}$ instead?

Should I use the number of atoms? Like this:

I have 0.002648 g of $\ce{Mn}$ = 4.82×10<sup>-5</sup> moles = 2.90×10<sup>19</sup> atoms. I then assume I have 2.90×10<sup>19</sup> molecules of $\ce{MnO2}$. Going backwards, this gives me 4.815×10<sup>-5</sup> moles = 4.187 mg. Would this be the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, your calculation is correct. But how do you know you have 1 mg of Mn in your sample? You have oxides, and that's what you weigh.

Comment: That was just to express the problem. The software gave me a concentration of Mn given in mg/L. I then multiplied with the dilution volume, and obtained the amount of Mn in my sample. This was 0.002648 g. I weighed in oxides, but these have been digested in acid and atomized in the argon plasma.

Comment: So your calculation is correct. Figure out how much moles of Mn is that, and then calculate how much would a similar amount (in moles) of MnO2 would weigh.

Comment: Well, not really. There are a lot of manganese oxides. Look at the mineral Hausmannite. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausmannite So you might very well end up with a total weight which is statistically significantly different that 100%.

Comment: Just digging up an old one here...Do you know if your sample was prepared for ash analysis? In other words, Was it combusted in a furnace to give anything from a light to dark gray powder prior to digestion and analysis?